# populate select element with json data and return filtered content of json

Tags: javascript, json

I want to display only parts of a .json that I scraped with [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/).
the scrapy output looks something like this and has about 500 entries:

data.json

```
[
{
"Content":["<h2>Heading of Paragraph1</h2><p>the actual pargraph1</p>"], 
"Titel": ["Heading of Paragraph1"]
}
,

{
"Content": ["<h2>Heading of Paragraph2</h2><p>the actual pargraph2</p>"], 
"Titel": ["Heading of Paragraph2"]
}
,
{
"Content": ["<h2>Heading of Paragraph3</h2><p>the actual pargraph3</p>"], 
"Titel": ["Heading of Paragraph3"]
}
]
```

What I want to do is to generate a list of All the "Titel" elements for the user to choose from. Then the website should display the chosen paragraphs.
I figured out that  some javascript are probably the way to go. I plan to use [chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) later to make the UI usable.

So far I came up with this html

index.html

```
    <body>
  <form action="/returnselected_paragraphs.js">
    <select name="pargraphs" multiple>
      <option value="Heading of Pargraph1">Heading of Paragraph1</option>
      <option value="Heading of Pargraph2">Heading of Paragraph2</option>
      <option value="Heading of Pargraph3">Heading of Paragraph3</option>
      <!-- this should be genereated by javascript with data from the json --!>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<h1>output</h1>
<h2>Heading of Paragraph1</h2><p>the actual pargraph1</p>
<h2>Heading of Paragraph2</h2><p>the actual pargraph2</p>
<!-- this should be genereated by javascript with data from json--!>
```

My problem is the javascript.
I found [this code on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bbnj95y6/)  which seems similar to what I want, but the data is formated differently. I don't know how to adapt it to my data.

I put my idea here: https://jsfiddle.net/jtxzerpu/

Thank you all for your time, I hope I did stick to all the rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

- Iterate the array and create select
- Bind change event on select on which content should be rendered.

**Demo**

```js
var arr = [{
    "Content": ["<h2>Heading of Paragraph1</h2><p>the actual pargraph1</p>"],
    "Titel": ["Heading of Paragraph1"]
  },
  {
    "Content": ["<h2>Heading of Paragraph2</h2><p>the actual pargraph2</p>"],
    "Titel": ["Heading of Paragraph2"]
  }, {
    "Content": ["<h2>Heading of Paragraph3</h2><p>the actual pargraph3</p>"],
    "Titel": ["Heading of Paragraph3"]
  }
];

//prepare the options first
var options = arr.map( function( item ){
   return "<option value='" + item.Titel[0] + "'>"+ item.Titel[0] + "</option>"
} ).join( "" );

//set all the options to select and then bind change event
$( "select" ).html( options ).change( function(){
   $( "#paraContent" ).html( "" );
   var val = $(this).val();
   $( "#paraContent" ).html( val.map( function( title ){
      return arr.find( (s) => s.Titel[0] == title ).Content[0];
   }).join( "</br>" ) )
   //console.log(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/returnselected_paragraphs.js">
    <select name="pargraphs" multiple>
    </select>
    <p id="paraContent">
       
    </p>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
```

Comment: thank you very much! it works here on the site, but if I save the frist box as returnselected_paragraphs.js and the second as index.html to the same dir it doesn't do anything

Comment: Not able to relate your new problem with with the one you have described in your original question here. Could you help me understand how they are related?

Comment: I just had problems loading the javascript. just added it to the html with a  <script type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 0):

You can build the options list easily:

```
const options = json_data.reduce(
    function (fragment, item)
    {
        const option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = item.Titel[0];
        option.textContent = option.value;
        fragment.appendChild(option);
        return fragment;
    },
    document.createDocumentFragment()
);
```

Then append the options to your select (the document fragment will "merge" with the select and disappear, don't worry).

Answer (score 0):

From your reference on jsfiddle, you can modify that to the code below:

```
    var data = [
{
"Content":["<h2>Heading of Paragraph1</h2><p>the actual pargraph1</p>"], 
"Titel": ["Heading of Paragraph1"]
}
,

{
"Content": ["<h2>Heading of Paragraph2</h2><p>the actual pargraph2</p>"], 
"Titel": ["Heading of Paragraph2"]
}
,
{
          "Content": ["<h2>Heading of Paragraph3</h2><p>the actual 
           pargraph3</p>"], 
         "Titel": ["Heading of Paragraph3"]
       }
      ]

      $.each(data, function () {
       var $option = $('<option/>').text(this.Titel[0]).val(this.Titel[0]);
        $option.data("content",this.Content[0])
       $('#selectCompany').append($option);
       });
```

Here is the link to your modified code in action:
https://jsfiddle.net/azqxhjgx/

You can use click event on option to display the content of the object where you want, something like this:

```
$("#selected > option").click(function(){
    // do whatever with $this.data("content")
})
```