# filter several json files with select elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The code below (in the interactive snippet) works well as long as there is only one select Item, it let's me choose chapters from a json file and prints them below.

How can I have several  elements that are from two different arrays?
Of course I have to change arr into another variable name.
But how do I specify which select element I want to feed?

**Disclaimer:** I got the [code from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47225477/3503111) and don't completely understand how it works

javascript and html

```js
var arr = [{
    "Content": ["<h2>Heading of Paragraph1</h2><p>the actual pargraph1</p>"],
    "Titel": ["Heading of Paragraph1"]
  },
  {
    "Content": ["<h2>Heading of Paragraph2</h2><p>the actual pargraph2</p>"],
    "Titel": ["Heading of Paragraph2"]
  }, {
    "Content": ["<h2>Heading of Paragraph3</h2><p>the actual pargraph3</p>"],
    "Titel": ["Heading of Paragraph3"]
  }
];

//prepare the options first
var options = arr.map( function( item ){
   return "<option value='" + item.Titel[0] + "'>"+ item.Titel[0] + "</option>"
} ).join( "" );

//set all the options to select and then bind change event
$( "select" ).html( options ).change( function(){
   $( "#paraContent" ).html( "" );
   var val = $(this).val();
   $( "#paraContent" ).html( val.map( function( title ){
      return arr.find( (s) => s.Titel[0] == title ).Content[0];
   }).join( "</br>" ) )
   //console.log(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/returnselected_paragraphs.js">
    <select name="pargraphs" multiple>
    </select>
    <p id="paraContent">
       
    </p>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
```

**this is what I tried**

https://jsfiddle.net/rba1amo7/

As you can see, it's loading the second dataset into both elements

Comment: i couldnt get what you mean by How can I have several elements that are from two different arrays? are you saying that you would have several arrays and every array would be assigned to a separate select element and you need to relate arrays to selects?

Comment: I mean, `$( "select" )` will obviously select all select elements on the page.  If you had multiple and you only wanted to change a single one in one case, and another in another case, you'd have to throw either a class or an id on the selects to identify and differentiate them for your $() lookup.  Does this make sense?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I basically whant to have serveal times the same code on one page, just for different json files.

Comment: @Taplar Yes it does, I am new to javascript, how do I hand over the id or class? that is my issue

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/  Good resource.  Most, if not all, css selectors work as jquery selectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code from @coderbyheart overwrote the content of the paragraph, so I made it an extra parameter. this does what I want

```js
var arr = [{
        "Content": ["<h2>Heading of Paragraph1</h2><p>the actual pargraph1</p>"],
        "Titel": ["Heading of Paragraph1"]
      },
      {
        "Content": ["<h2>Heading of Paragraph2</h2><p>the actual pargraph2</p>"],
        "Titel": ["Heading of Paragraph2"]
      }, {
        "Content": ["<h2>Heading of Paragraph3</h2><p>the actual pargraph3</p>"],
        "Titel": ["Heading of Paragraph3"]
      }
    ];

var arr2 = [
    {
        "Content": ["<h2>Heading of Paragraph4</h2><p>the actual pargraph4</p>"],
        "Titel": ["Heading of Paragraph4"]
      }
];    

const fillSelect = (data, select,para) => {
    // prepare the options first
    var options = data.map(item => "<option value='" + item.Titel[0] + "'>"+ item.Titel[0] + "</option>").join( "" );

    //set all the options to select and then bind change event
    select
        .html( options )
        .change(function() {
            para.html( "" );
            var val = $(this).val();
            para.html( val.map( title => data.find( s => s.Titel[0] == title ).Content[0]).join( "</br>" ) )
    });
}

// Now you can reuse the code:

fillSelect(arr, $('select[name=pargraphs]'),$( "#paraContent" ));
fillSelect(arr2, $('select[name=pargraphs2]'),$( "#paraContent2" ));
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <form action="/returnselected_paragraphs.js">
        <select name="pargraphs" multiple>
        </select>
        <select name="pargraphs2" multiple>
        </select>
        <p id="paraContent">
        </p>
        <p id="paraContent2"> 
        </p>

           
        
      
      </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be turn the code that fills the select element into a reusable function:

```js
var arr = [{
        "Content": ["<h2>Heading of Paragraph1</h2><p>the actual pargraph1</p>"],
        "Titel": ["Heading of Paragraph1"]
      },
      {
        "Content": ["<h2>Heading of Paragraph2</h2><p>the actual pargraph2</p>"],
        "Titel": ["Heading of Paragraph2"]
      }, {
        "Content": ["<h2>Heading of Paragraph3</h2><p>the actual pargraph3</p>"],
        "Titel": ["Heading of Paragraph3"]
      }
    ];

const arr2 = [
    {
        "Content": ["<h2>Heading of Paragraph4</h2><p>the actual pargraph4</p>"],
        "Titel": ["Heading of Paragraph4"]
      }
];    

const fillSelect = (data, select) => {
    // prepare the options first
    var options = data.map(item => "<option value='" + item.Titel[0] + "'>"+ item.Titel[0] + "</option>").join( "" );

    //set all the options to select and then bind change event
    select
        .html( options )
        .change(function() {
            $( "#paraContent" ).html( "" );
            var val = $(this).val();
            $( "#paraContent" ).html( val.map( title => data.find( s => s.Titel[0] == title ).Content[0]).join( "</br>" ) )
    });
}

// Now you can reuse the code:

fillSelect(arr, $('select[name=pargraphs]'));
fillSelect(arr2, $('select[name=pargraphs2]'));
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <form action="/returnselected_paragraphs.js">
        <select name="pargraphs" multiple>
        </select>
        <select name="pargraphs2" multiple>
        </select>
        <p id="paraContent">
           
        </p>
        <input type="submit">
      </form>
```

Comment: can "const arr2 " also be "var arr2"?

Comment: Check out this article on the meaning of const: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const